# Are Employers more likely to hire someone with "developer bootcamp" experience vs. Self-Learning?

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search, internship, work-experience

Can attending developer bootcamps such as [DevCamps](http://www.devcamps.org), [AppAcademy](http://www.appacademy.io/), be considered enough real-world experience for employment? How useful is attending these types of schools as preparation for employment?

I am planning to attend one of these schools, but since the tuition cost is pretty expensive for me and it's not easy to be accepted to these kind of schools. How about if self-learning it using books, online resources and then build web apps? Consider someone who has little bit coding experience or CS student.

Comment: Woah, you have about 10 things you are trying to ask here. I suggest reading the [FAQ] and focusing this to one specific thing. I've read through here a couple times now and am not sure what your question is - it looks like you are searching for general advice or feedback on your ideas (which is discussed as being off topic in the [FAQ]).

Comment: If you want to be a web developer, you need to build some websites. Whether you do this on your own or as part of a boot camp doesn't matter as much. Real ability to do something with a track record of having things done is more important than bullet points on a resume.

Comment: @enderland no offends I just new guy here and I never this question on here. I just want people opinion on it. Yes, I read FAQ and I did not see this Q as off-topic Q

Comment: There are good questions here, please follow @enderland's advice and refactor and re-ask.

Comment: **"How do I learn to be a..." / "How do I perform the job of a ..."** - Has been declared off topic and that is basically what this is a variation of (Can I be Learn an X doin Y)

Comment: If the question is, "How would I use the experience of..." that could be a useful, on-topic question though it is a bit different than what the ending questions indicate.

Comment: @MDMoore - Thank you for making those edits and for your efforts! Unfortunately, I agree this still isn't quite on-topic. If you're still adamant about getting it reopened, you may be able to get some advice in [chat]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Real world experience, yes.  Professional experience, no.  It would likely be seen as educational or training experience.  Depending on your purpose for attending the useful could vary from great to nothing as there is something to be said for why are you wanting to use these camps.  I could picture them as useful to get exposure if you have a social learning style or want to build up a network on the one hand.  If your plan is to work for Google or Apple, then I'm not sure these will be great stepping stones to get you there.

While you can learn stuff yourself, there is a question of being able to communicate what you've done and handle things like a whiteboard question in an interview.  If someone asks you a question like [FizzBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz), are you going to be able to articulate a well thought out answer or are you going to be silent for the next few minutes?  [Why Can't Programmers.. Program?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) would be Jeff Atwood's perspective on this kind of thing that if you do learn it all on your own this could be the problem you'd encounter.

My suggestion for getting useful experience is to consider volunteering to help non-profits with their websites or get involved in the community,e.g. meetups, user groups, and Hackathons, that may be a way to find companies wanting to invest in someone that doesn't have a lot of experience but does have a lot of potential.  Do realize that lots of people have potential so it is more about how you'll use this.

If you are a college student, there may be a department responsible for helping graduates find jobs which is how I found my first job after university was through the Career Services department at my school.

Comment: Yes, I wnt to career service on my college. Seems like they don't have any job or intern as Web Developer. I just wonder too. I might try it again in the future.